# Any Best tutorial Exercise for AdventureWorks2012 available

Tags: database, sql-server-2012-express, adventureworks

I have installed AdventureWorks2012 database  on my Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express. Currently I need and want to do some tutorial exercise. Is there any Tutorial available on web. I have been doing a lot of searching nothing looking good to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167593.aspx
Also you can download and see the examples of Begining Microsoft Sql Server Programing book.